# Панель в phpstorm справа как называется

Tags: phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как называется полоса справа на картинке и как ее можно подключить в phpstorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полоса справа в Sublime Text называется - Minimap.

В PhpStorm есть пользовательский плагин с названием [CodeGlance](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275-codeglance), который похож на Minimap, но не точно такой же.